# Firebase: How do I implement secure session tracking?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

**EDIT**: **To try to simplify this question... at a very basic level, and I believe this has to be a fairly basic need of a session system... how do we have a SECURE session tracker without breaking onDisconnect functionality? If you add security rules, onDisconnect doesn't work, if you DON'T add security rules anyone can "spoof" a login session by writing to the unprotected table or deleting someone else's presence.**

I'm trying to solve a problem where "onDisconnect" is not being called because my security rules only allow the logged in user to write their presence data in /sessions/$userid/"true" ... onDisconnect works so long as that user is logged in, but if that user closes their browser AFTER they have been logged out, or logged out due to timeout, onDisconnect gets blocked by the security rules.

At first I thought... "oh, I can just trace back to where logout happens and put in another clean up of session presence there." but had I thought that through more I would realize that the auth = newFirebaseSimpleLogin callback "else" block seems to be the only way to detect log outs. ON TOP OF THAT, the callback is returned AFTER the logout occurs so that returns me to square one where I need to be logged in so that the onDisconnect call can remove my session, but by this time, I'm already logged out.

Am I missing something? Is there a pre-logout call I'm not aware of? Is there something special I can do in the security rules file that will allow onDisconnect to remove sessions post logout?

Here is the security rules block I have for the "table" in question:

```
"sessions":{
    "$user":{
      ".write": "$user == auth.uid"
    }
},
```

And in the JS it's just simple:

```
var con = ref.sessions[user].push(true);
con.onDisconnect().remove();
```

And as expected, since I'm not logged in onDisconnect I get:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /sessions/simplelogin:16 failed: permission_denied
```

EDIT: What's with the downvote? =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest removing the presence bit before calling logout().

If you then want to track "presence" of a logged out user, you could either set a new presence bit as an un-authed user, or you could log in anonymously:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-anonymous.html

Comment: As @andrew-lee mentioned, you'll want to remove the presence bit before calling `.logout()`, because your security rule is requiring an authenticated user, which is checked at the time of the write (in this case - on client disconnection) not just at the time when you called `ref.onDisconnect().set()`.